i have a data extracted from the leap motion i don't know how to classify the hand gestures presented in it where it's in the format excel?
I'd like to use a classifier for the hand gestures presented in the file extracted from the leap motion controller, which is a file in .xlsx format, but I can't find a way of using this file in a special classifier.i don(t understad where is te problem exactly it's in the data or what ????
I've tried to use the data for 1 D cnn and the same for knn but I'm still faced with the problem that the data needs to be adapted to these types of classifiers in order to work on them and do the prediction steps to classify them later.
